# AngularJS : ng-if and ng-repeat on another scope in the inner loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have the following snippet:

```
<tr ng-repeat="column in allAttrsForPorject.gridStructure.columns">
    <td>{{column.title}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="newViewModal.column.checked"></td>
</tr>
```

It writing out a few table rows.

I would like to display the checked checkbox  if value in another scope (array of the object) will have the same given attribute name and set ng-checked param (true or false) based on attr. value from second array.

It means to use inner loop inside the ng-repeat, something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="column in allAttrsForPorject.gridStructure.columns">
    <td>{{column.title}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="secondObjectToCheck in anotherObject.gridStructure.columns">
         <input type="checkbox" 
                      ng-if="secondObjectToCheck.name == column.name" 
                      ng-checked="secondObjectToCheck.column.checked">
     </td>
 </tr>
```

How can i do it please in the AngularJS?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Not sure what the root issue is here. Is your problem matching the current "column" to the object in the other scope (anotherObject.gridStructure.columns)?

Comment: I need recursively compare (search) selected value from one one array against the second array.

Comment: Have you tried a filter? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter These have a comparatar function you can build to make the comparison. Something like: secondObjectToCheck in anotherObject.gridStructure.columns | filter : column.attributeToCompare : comparison(secondObjectToCheck.attributeToCompare, column.attributeToCompare)  I haven't done it this way but this might help